# Assign rows of a result set with same id into a Java list using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm using Hibernate to retrieve some data from a database. The result set returned by the SQL query I'm using, is something like the following:

```
SourceId | TargetId
1        | 10
1        | 11
1        | 12
2        | 13
2        | 14
```

Right now I'm having something like the following class:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "myQuery", resultSetMapping = "myMapping", 
    query = "select source.id id1, target.id id2
            + "from someTable source "
            + "left join associationTable association on source.id=association.sourceId "
            + "left join someTable target on association.targetId=target.id "
            + "where source.id in(?1)")

@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "myMapping", 
            entities = @EntityResult(entityClass = DBCalculationElement.class, fields = {
    @FieldResult(name = "targetId", column = "targetId"),
    @FieldResult(name = "sourceId", column = "sourceId") }))

public class MyClass {

    private String sourceId;
    private String targetId;

        public String getSourceId() {
            return sourceId;
        }

        public String getTargetId() {
            return targetId;
        }
}
```

Even though everything is working fine and I'm getting the results I need, in some cases the result set is really huge (thousands of rows) so it takes several minutes to actually get the data. I'm aware that Hibernate is not the best solution performance-wise when it comes to really big result sets, but I'm trying to avoid using raw JDBC.

One workaround would be to have a list of strings as targetId. This way, and using the above resultSet as an example, I would get 2 objects, one with

```
sourceId = "1"
```

which also has a list of targetIds containing the following:

```
targetId = <"10", "11", "12">
```

and something similar for the second object with sourceId="2".

Does anyone know how can I do this using Hibernate? How can I map several rows to a list in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once, i solved this problem by writing a stored procedure.
u can write stored proc to retun comma separated values of target id for each source id and in your main query use distinct to get unique sourceId.

Hope, will work for u also.

Comment: Well, I cannot modify anything in the database, including creating stored procedures. But this solution with the comma separated text will work :) I just have to modify my query to get all the sourceId as a comma separated string :) Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm aware that Hibernate is not the best solution performance-wise when it comes to really big result sets

First of all that is not true.

> ...in some cases the result set is really huge (thousands of rows)...

This is not *huge* for a DBMS like postgres, mysql and so on...

You should consider using setMaxResults and setFirstResult for paginating your query. (it is like offset and limit).

And you should take a look at your machine and JVM configurations, if you are getting performance lacks with such a simple query (yes, there is joins. but still, simple).

Comment: Hi bluefoot, thanks for your reply. Well, the problem I described above is an oversimplification of the actual problem...I just included all the information that are relevant to what I want to do. In reality the query involves a lot of joins with multiple criteria. Sorry for not clarifying that. Nevertheless, when I run the query directly to the database I'm getting the results back in <1 sec while in Hibernate I have to wait at least 8 mins.
The solution of setting a maximum number of results is not feasible because I need all the results so that I can manipulate them programmatically.

Comment: now we have a problem :) can you post your hibernate version and hibernate configuration file?